# Facebook Login Button error onclick

Tags: android, facebook

I tried following the intstructions for adding a facebook login for my app. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2

I did the step for Add the Login Button.

It displays properly on my screen however I get the following error when I click it:

```
Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 3073
    Log in attempt failed: LoginActivity could not be started
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:382)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:262)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:693)
            at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:310)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do I need to handle user clicks in my code.  Somehow I thought this was inbuilt in the button. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add loginactivity to your manifest

Comment: @RobertRowntree, I suggest you expand on this and add it as answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Facebook SDK 4+, you need the following in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
```