# Android FacebookException : Login attempt failed

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I am using ParseFacebookUtils to login to my app from Facebook.

LoginActivity's onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                  
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(LoginActivity.this,
                    Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_photos", "user_birthday"),
                    new LogInCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user == null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "User logged in through Facebook!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Application class onCreate:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, app_id, client_key);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Crash error:

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: Log in attempt failed: LoginActivity could not be started
   at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:382)
   at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:262)
   at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:150)
   at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationProvider.logInAsync(ParseAuthenticationProvider.java:57)
   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInAsync(ParseFacebookUtils.java:259)
   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:155)
   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:167)
   at com.example.app.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:48)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I keep getting the above crash when tapping on the login button.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I have set the client id for Facebook and Parse in the strings.xml

**UPDATE:**

Facebook SDK v4.0.1

Custom button onClick()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334396/facebook-login-button-error-onclick), the above is needed in Facebook SDK 4.+.

Answer (score 3):

**@kRiZ**: Yes.you forgot to add the **`com.facebook.FacebookActivity`** activity to *AndroidManifest.xml*.

This Activity is a necessary part of the overall **Facebook SDK**, but is not meant to be used directly. Add this Activity to your **AndroidManifest.xml** to ensure proper handling of Facebook SDK features.

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)  To use Facebook Login or Share, also add the **FacebookActivity** to the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

And

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Where `@string/facebook_app_id` is your **Facebook Application ID** .

This is how **facebook authorization** process will work.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. This is new from v4.+ of the SDK, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a callback for the button before you can use it:

1.Declare a CallbackManager object:

```
 CallbackManager callbackManager;
```

2. In your onCreate method add this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  ...
}
```

3. Define onActivityResult and add this line:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Esto es necesario para el uso del botón de facebook
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, sorry. `Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider`

Comment: Your error is due to a wrong facebook contiguration with your application, not with the login. Loot at this post, maybe you can find the solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698419/android-failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-wakizashi-provider-platf